He didn't know that the meeting had/has been rescheduled
John, Peter, Rick, and some other colleagues from the office had agreed in person to meet at 4:00 pm to discuss business matters. However, John sent everyone an email informing them that he had rescheduled the meeting to 3:00 pm. Peter, who hadn't received John's email, informed Rick that he had to leave but assured him he would be back in time for the meeting at 4:00 pm. Rick then informed Peter that the meeting had been rescheduled and that he should return before 3:00 pm. Later, during lunch, Rick spoke with John and, among other things, mentioned:
Peter didn't receive your email. He didn't know that the meeting had/has been rescheduled. If I hadn't told him, he wouldn't be joining us at 3:00 pm.
Would you use "had" or "has" in this context? Thank you.

has if the meeting is happening now or in the future, had if the meeting already happened in the past

Specifically, if the rescheduled meeting has not yet occurred, though originally planned for a previous time, or not,, has would be used.
